# Why do we need to send the log messages to the elasticsearch?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

Firstly, I'm very new to IT and in my 7 months of the short experience, I've never gotten the chance to see the production code.
But while learning Elasticsearch, I came to know that we send the logging messages to the Elasticsearch. For what purpose, we need to send logs to the Elasticsearch?

> Here, by "logs", what I'm understanding is that what I use to print
>   using log4j/logback. Am I right? or is any other kind of logging?

Answer (score 1):

when you have millions line of log per hour, you could not use traditional tools for search in log files. by sending tons of logs to elasticsearch (text search engine) you can find the problem more quickly.

Comment: Are these log messages are the same what we use to log using log4j/logback? Or it is about any other kind of **logging system**? And can you please be more specific on a real time example/use-case?

Comment: you can send any kind of logs to elasticsearch. you need extra tools for parsing log and send it to elasticsearch. (tool: logstash. ) . log4j is a kind of log types. you can send syslog or any other format like JSON.